# Maximum and minimum of the following function

Tags: calculus

1. $y = \sin x - 2x$ on $[0,1]$

Here I got:

$y' = \cos x - 2$

$\cos x = -2$

How do I approach from here?

2. $y = \sqrt{1 + x^2} - 3x$

Here I got:

$x^2 = -9/8$

Not sure how to proceed again.

Thanks for all the help in advance.

Comment: (1): $\cos x \ge  -1$ for all $x$, so $y'\not = 0$, so where are the maxima and minima?

Answer (score 1):

1) Since $y'=\cos x-2< 0$, $y$ is a decreasing function. So for any $x\in [0,1]$, $$0=y(0)\ge y(x) \ge y(1)=\sin 1-2.$$

2) Suppose that the interval is $[0,1]$. Since $y'=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}-3\le \frac{x}{\sqrt{2x}}-3=\sqrt{\frac{x}{2}}-3\le \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}-3<0$, $y$ is a decreasing function.

So for any $x\in [0,1]$, $$1=y(0)\ge y(x) \ge y(1)=\sqrt{2}-3.$$

May it helps!

Answer (score 0):

If the derivative always exists and is never zero, the minimum and maximum come at the ends of the interval. For 1, evaluate it at the end points.  For 2, you did not specify the interval.  Is there one?  Otherwise the function may not attain its minimum and maximum.